# Hiding Php Extension Htaccess code Display Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this htaccess code to hide my website php extension
Currently I am testing on "localhost" by WampServer Application

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Displaying Error Like:

```
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log."
```

(I Know There are many discussions on hiding page extension though i facing this problem)
How Can I Properly Hide the php Extension? Please Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: you need to enable `mod_rewrite`, click wamp icon, then apache and apache module, check rewrite module

Comment: thanx burak. its worked now succesfully..